# Missing business_management permission when trying to create token for system user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a system user token for one of my apps as described here in the Facebook API documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/#systemusertoken

I'm using the Graph API explorer to make the call, include the correct parameters (appsecret_proof, business_app etc.) but receive the following error:

`(#200) Requires business_management permission to manage the object`

It is true that the `access_token` I'm using when making the call does not have the `business_management` permission, but I don't understand why. The user that is making the call is Administrator for the app in question and has all rights I could possibly give. Also, for my other app, the permission shows up correctly when creating the user token and I cannot spot any difference in the configuration of the two apps.

I'm wondering if I need to put the app (which is a mobile game) through app review, but that seems kind of wrong because I don't want to request that permission from users or anything, I just want to use my administrator account to generate a system user token, which is a one-time action. The other app that correctly shows the permission also didn't go through app review, and both apps don't use Facebook for anything user facing, not even for logging in.

I feel like I'm completely on the wrong track and probably don't see the real problem here, but I'm also out of ideas. Is there something obvious I'm missing or anything else that could cause this permission not to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it now by putting the app back into development mode, which apparently allows all permissions to be granted. Creating a system user token worked fine and the system user is able to make API calls even after the app is set back to "live".